# ConstructorArgument.Inject breaks where Kernel.Get works

Tags: c#, ninject

Given the following classes:

```
interface IFoo { }

class Foo : IFoo { }

class Bar
{
    public Bar(IFoo foo) { }
}
```

And the binding:

```
Bind<Bar>().ToConstructor(ctx => new Bar(ctx.Inject<Foo>()));
```

Calling `kernel.Get<Bar>()` throws the following exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Ninject.ActivationException' occurred in Ninject.dll
Additional information: Error activating IFoo
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
Activation path:
    2) Injection of dependency IFoo into parameter foo of constructor of type Bar
    1) Request for Bar
```

However, if I change my bindings to:

```
Bind<Bar>().ToMethod(ctx => new Bar(ctx.Kernel.Get<Foo>()));
```

I can get an instance of `Bar` as expected.

Why am I getting that exception? I was under the impression the two bindings are almost identical, and in both cases an instance of `IFoo` is never activated.

(Not) working fiddle can be seen here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qmPFhr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by ninject. The type specified in `ctx.Inject<>` must match the type of the constructor parameter *exactly*. Ninject is never actually executing your `new Bar(...)`, it only analyses the expression to determine which constructor to use and how to inject the values.

There's two ways to adapt your code to make it work:

- change the constructor of `Bar` to receive a `Foo` intead of an `IFoo`.
- change the `ToConstructor` binding of `Bar` to have `ctx.Inject<>()` match the constructor of `Bar` (`ctx.Inject<IFoo>()`) and create a binding for `IFoo`:

.

```
Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>();
Bind<Bar>().ToConstructor(ctx => new Bar(ctx.Inject<IFoo>()));
```

### As per your request for documentation

No it's not documented in any other document than the source/api, that `ctx.Inject<>` is not actually executed, ever. However, it is quite obvious from the parameter of the method being an `Expression<Func<..>>` and not a `Func<..>`. If it would be executed, a `Func<..>` would suffice. `Expression`'s are there so you can analyze their contents.

Also, when looking at the source of [`BindingBuilder.cs`](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/blob/c18c3120ba0cc93e79c1d7a56785866ed1bc6669/src/Ninject/Planning/Bindings/BindingBuilder.cs), the `Inject<T1>` method actually only does one thing: throwing an exception:

```
public T1 Inject<T1>()
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("This method is for declaration that a parameter shall be injected only! Never call it directly.");
}
```

Also see: http://ivanitskyi.blogspot.com/2013/06/linq-func-vs-expression.html

If, however, you're referring to documentation regarding that the type `T` at `Inject<T>` must be an exact match: The answer is no, again. I couldn't find any documentation about it. However, as it's open source, we can again resort to having a look at the implementation. Again, it's found in [`BindingBuilder.cs`](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/blob/c18c3120ba0cc93e79c1d7a56785866ed1bc6669/src/Ninject/Planning/Bindings/BindingBuilder.cs), which contains:

```
protected IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<TImplementation> InternalToConstructor<TImplementation>(
    Expression<Func<IConstructorArgumentSyntax, TImplementation>> newExpression)
{
    var ctorExpression = newExpression.Body as NewExpression;
    if (ctorExpression == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The expression must be a constructor call.", "newExpression");
    }

    this.BindingConfiguration.ProviderCallback = StandardProvider.GetCreationCallback(ctorExpression.Type, ctorExpression.Constructor);
    this.BindingConfiguration.Target = BindingTarget.Type;
    this.AddConstructorArguments(ctorExpression, newExpression.Parameters[0]);

    return new BindingConfigurationBuilder<TImplementation>(this.BindingConfiguration, this.ServiceNames, this.Kernel);
}
```

And you can go from there an have a look at `AddConstructorArguments` and how that stuff works, and eventually you'll find out why it behaves as it does ;-)
(I'm not going to to that for you)

Comment: Are you able to point to the documentation page supporting this claim?

Comment: I've updated the answer to cover your question about documentation. Long story short: this is not documented explicitly.